# Write parquet in java

Tags: java, parquet

I want to write a parquet file in standalone java, in local filesystem (not on hadoop).
How to do this?

I know I can do this easily with spark, but I need to do this in standalone java so no hadoop, spark, ecc.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post: http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2015/12/02/how-to-write-data-into-parquet/

Short version is you need to define/provide a schema and utilize the appropriate ParquetWriter.